# Как организовать random на C?

Tags: c

Для инициализации массива 10*10, чтобы самому не вводить каждый элемент, а через random заполнить массив.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что-то вроде такого:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

/* Размер матрицы */
#define SIZE 10

void main()
{
    int matrix[SIZE][SIZE];

    srand(time(NULL));

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
            matrix[i][j] = rand();
}
```

Comment: а разве в С не int main(void){return 0;}?

Comment: Это C99: gcc -std=c99 filename

Comment: вроде запись gcc main.c && ./a.out намного приятнее=) хотя без понятия.... 

Answer (score 2):

Вообще-то функции генерации псевдослучайной последовательности используют линейно-конгруэнтный генератор с заданными коэффициентами. У каждой фирмы эти коэффициенты свои. Для 32-битных версий эти генераторы генерируют последовательности с периодом повторения 2^32. Разрядность чисел можно изменить с 15 до 24 бит без существенной потери статистических свойств. А увеличить период можно только желательно перейдя на 64-битную арифметику. Но там надо найти уже новые значения коэффициентов.
Для Вашей задачи это не принципиально.
Но выражение "rand() возвращает псевдослучайные числа из маленького диапазона (0 - 32767), кроме того у него короткий цикл." в корне не верно!

Answer (score 1):

rand() возвращает псевдослучайные числа из маленького диапазона (0 - 32767), кроме того у него короткий цикл.

Лучше использовать random()/srandom() у него диапазон 2^31 , а цикл очень длинный. Правда в MinGW есть только rand().

Comment: Не увидел преимуществ у random/srandom. Значения ограничены все равно все тем же RAND_MAX (который как минимум 32767)

Comment: А Вы в чем смотрели ? В Windows: MinGW random() нет, только rand() RAND_MAX = 0x7fff, в Cygwin и Interix (SFU) rand() и random() возвращают RAND_MAX = 0x7fffffff и действительно обе функции выдают в этом диапазоне, но при одинаковой начальной установке разные последовательности. На длину цикла не смотрел. Линукса под рукой нет, но помнню, что в RedHat rand() выдавал до 32767, а random() до 0x7fffffff. А в общем это все может сказаться только на переносимости алгоритма.

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/BSD-Random.html